# How to pip install a package that needs cython code built?

Tags: python, pip, cython

I have Cython code that wraps C++ code, which needs compiled before running. To do this, I use the following line: 
`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

However, a great thing about python is the `setup.py` file and the ability to install packages to `pip`. All previous version of my code were able to be installed to pip and then called without being moved to a local directory for whoever was using it. Just like numpy, scipy, etc.

Is there any way to pip install a package and have the Cython files compiled at the same time?

Comment: You'll have to distribute the backend too

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by distributing the backend? @MadPhysicist

Comment: You'll have to provide the C++ code to link against

Comment: Right but how do I tell pip to build that C++ code (made possible by pyx and pxd files) when I do a pip install path/to/package.zip?

Comment: And what happens when you call pip install? Did you try it?

Comment: See also https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules

Comment: @ead yeah I tried it, but I’ll mess around with it some more tomorrow. I’ll check those docs out as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the ability to run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, and it works. A `pip install` is essentially a build not inplace. Therefore, if you run `pip install path/to/folder.zip` and everything is properly defined in setup.py, then the necessary files with be compiled and able to be called in the package.